# NSUrl exc_bad_instruction?

Tags: swift

I am trying to follow this tutorial and after some minor trial and error runs I have ran into a problem that I don't quite understand. I am receiving this error(?) exc_bad_instruction. I have read that it happens usually when you try to unwrap a nil or the nil isn't valid?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell:iGameTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? iGameTableViewCell
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("iGameTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? iGameTableViewCell
    }

    if let pfObject = object {
        cell?.gameNameLabel?.text = pfObject["name"] as? String

        var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
        if votes == nil {
            votes = 0
        }
        cell?.gameVotesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"

        var credit:String? = pfObject["author"] as? String
        if credit != nil {
            cell?.gameCreditLabel?.text = "\(credit!)"
        }

        cell?.gameImageView?.image = nil
        if var urlString:String? = pfObject["url"] as? String {
            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)
            if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
                var error:NSError?
                var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().cancelAllOperations()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    cell?.gameImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                })
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these two lines:

```
 var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)
 if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
```

- First, you can't want them both; they both do the same thing in
  different ways.
- Second, the way the *first* line operates is dangerous. Delete it.
- Third, delete the exclamation mark from `urlString!` and the type
  declaration `NSURL?`.

Now you will just have this:

```
 if var url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
```

And that is safe and is how such unwrapping should look.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify: This is a terribly self-defeating thing to do:

```
if var urlString:String? = pfObject["url"] as? String
```

Here's why. The `if var ... =` or `if let ... =` construct unwraps the Optional on the right side of the equal sign. That is its purpose: to unwrap the Optional, safely. But by adding the `:String?` declaration, you wrap it right back up again in an Optional, thus defeating the entire purpose of this construct! You want to say this:

```
if var urlString = pfObject["url"] as? String
```

Now `urlString`, if it is anything at all, is an *unwrapped* String, which is what you're after.

Comment: I would probably replace the var with a let since it is a constant :]

Comment: Of course I agree, but as a teacher I'm just getting him over this hump right now.

Comment: Honestly thank you very much. You explained it very well. I totally over looked that those did the same thing. As far as everything else goes it works except for removing the exclamation mark from  `urlString!` creates an error but I left it and it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can apply matts answer to urlString as well to get rid of that exclamation mark.

Comment: No exclamation mark! Take the `String?` away from the declaration of `urlString`. That was your mistake. My answer is right but you need to use it in more places!

Comment: I added some further explanation to my answer. You need to get this construct right!